# make a column in sql if the minutes are higher than 15mins

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I want to make a column when the minutes (`LT Min`) are above 15min in the following code

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, cs.subscribeddate,cs.unsubscribeddate) as 'LT Min'
from customer cs
```

Any idea? Should I use IF?

Comment: Your question is unclear. your decision to make a column or not should not be dependant on a calculation on the data stored in the table. You either need the column or you don't. Do you mean you want to store data based on that calculation or not store it if below that amount?

Comment: Also please tag your questions correctly. Are you using mysql or are you using sql-server? You aren't using both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You are already showing how to get the difference in minutes. Now either use it to limit selected records, e.g:

```
select cs.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, cs.subscribeddate,cs.unsubscribeddate) as "LT Min"
from customer cs 
where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, cs.subscribeddate, cs.unsubscribeddate) > 15;
```

or select all rows and show the difference only when it's above 15:

```
select cs.*, 
  case when TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, cs.subscribeddate, cs.unsubscribeddate) > 15 then 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, cs.subscribeddate, cs.unsubscribeddate)
  end as "LT Min"
from customer cs;
```